# neo4j cypher query for filtering paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using neo4j to store data with nodes having 1 of 2 labels :`Person` and `Organization`. All nodes have a property :`name`

All the relationships are labeled `LinkedTo` and have a property :`score`. There might be multiple relations between one pair of `Person` and `Organization` nodes

I have used path queries to search paths between these nodes like:

```
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name =~ "(?i)person1"
MATCH (m:Organization) WHERE m.name =~ "(?i)organization1"
WITH m,n
MATCH p = (m)-[*1..4]-(n)
RETURN p ORDER BY length(p) LIMIT 10
```

This returns all paths (upto 10)

Now I want to find specific paths, with all relations involved having a `score=1`. Not sure how to achieve this, I started with `MATCH p = (m)-[f*1..4]-(n)` but it got a deprecation warning. So after some googling and trials and errors, I came up with this:

```
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name =~ "(?i)person1"
MATCH (m:Organization) WHERE m.name =~ "(?i)organization1"
WITH m,n
MATCH p = (m)-[*1..4]-(n)
WITH filter(x IN relationships(p) WHERE x.score=1) AS f
ORDER BY length(p)
UNWIND f AS ff
MATCH (a)-[ff]-(b)
RETURN a,b,ff LIMIT 10
```

But this is not correct and not clean and is giving me relationships and nodes that are not needed in the path.

This might be a basic cypher query but I am just a beginner and need help with this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have understand you are searching this query :

```
MATCH p = (m:Organization)-[rels*1..4]-(n:Person) 
WHERE 
    n.name =~ "(?i)person1" AND
    m.name =~ "(?i)organization1" AND
    all(r IN rels WHERE r.score=1)
RETURN p
ORDER BY length(p)
```

Due to `all(r IN rels WHERE r.score=1)`, Neo4j will just expand relationships in the path that have an attribute `score` set to `1`.

Also you should note that you are using a regex condition for the node `n` & `m`, and this operator can't use indexes !
If your goal is to have a case-insensitive search, I advise you to create a sanitize field (ex `_name`) to store the name in lower-case, and to replace your regex with a `CONTAINS` or `STARTS WITH`

Comment: Thankyou that was exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: So you can also accept the answer :( Have fun with your graph !

Comment: I did, I guess it didn't register it! Well I did it now!